# PPTP not working after some few random minutes

Tags: router, vpn

I use a VPN to connect to remote server from my computer. I have a Fedora and VPN is over PPTP.

Since I have changed my router vpn only keeps connection if I write my IP on router DMZ setting.

It's weird because, if I don't put my computer on router DMZ, the vpn is still up but the connections through vpn hangs.

Here the networkmanager log when PPTP internal ping also fails:

```
Sep 04 08:51:38 localhost.localdomain pptp[10014]: nm-pptp-service-9992 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Sep 04 08:51:38 localhost.localdomain pptp[10014]: nm-pptp-service-9992 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:719]: Echo Reply received.
Sep 04 08:52:38 localhost.localdomain pptp[10014]: nm-pptp-service-9992 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:719]: Echo Reply received.
Sep 04 08:52:38 localhost.localdomain pptp[10014]: nm-pptp-service-9992 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:721]: no more Echo Reply/Request packets will be reported.
```

I know I'm writing here few details, please, be free to ask for relevant information. Thanks.

Comment: Standard PPTP Warning: PPTP is insecure and has been deprecated for years. Do not use it.

Comment: Thanks @Spiff about your warning. The decision about VPN protocol is out of my hands.